# Set database sum of column values to single variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write  function to pull in all of the `INT` values from a database column and assign the sum of these values to one PHP variable.  This is the code I have so far, but it must contain some obvious error because it is causing my site to load a white page.

```
$total_drop_query = mysqli_query("SELECT total_drops FROM pi_data");

while ($drop_results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total_drop_query))
{
    $total_drop_count += $result['total_drops'];
}

mysqli_free_result($total_drop_query);
echo $total_drop_count;
```

Comment: why not just SELECT sum(total_drops) FROM pi_data ?

Comment: The problem is for sure as you do `$drop_results=` but then use just `$result[...]`... change so they match. Also consider use sum sql function. See below answer.

Comment: I fixed that match error, which I totally should have seen, and tried the sum function, but still a lovely blank page.
This function is being called by the index from a functions.php file.  The index is connecting to the db seperate to the function, could that be the problem?

Comment: Fixed it.  I'm an idiot.
I included my functions.php twice.

Because yunno, extra sure and all that.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is:

```
while ($drop_results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total_drop_query))
{
    $total_drop_count += $drop_results['total_drops'];
}
```

..although a SUM(columns) in the Query is the preferred solution.

Comment: As I wrote in my comment ;)